# Twitter card not working

Tags: meta-tags

**My meta tags for twitter in site:**

```
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:site" content="....">
<meta property="twitter:title" content=".....">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="test description">
<meta property="twitter:image" content="....">
```

I even tried with **twitter:image:url** and also allowed twitter bot in **robot.txt**  but no luck till now

Answer (score 5):

Use `name` instead of `property` in you meta tags Like :

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="....">
<meta name="twitter:title" content=".....">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="test description">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="....">
```

Answer (score 3):

May I know where did you test if the twitter card is working or not?
Did you check with https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator?

Also, sometimes the placement of the meta tags do matter, place them early in the head section but after the og (open graph) meta-tags.

Let me know what error you get(if any) on the card validator.

Comment: Do the placement of the meta tags really matter? I never recognize it, and I meet the same problem sometimes

Comment: @jansesun yes, surprisingly, they do matter!

Comment: I placed these tags at the end of the head section, doesn't seem to have an impact

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works, try changing `twitter:image` to `twitter:image:src` and make sure that the image fulfills the size requirements:

#### smallest size supported

- summary: 144x144px
- summary_large_image: 300x157px

#### Largest size supported

In both cases the maximum is 4096x4096px and at most 5MB.

Answer (score 0):

## Twitter share url

```
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:site" content="....">
<meta property="twitter:title" content=".....">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="test description">
<meta property="twitter:image" content="....">

Share Url : <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=your_url">SHARE</a>
```

It will work only on https

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's card validator would return `No meta tags found` for me until I added the `Content-Type: text/html` header to the server's response.

From what I gather, Twitterbot doesn't even try to parse the page unless the server responds with the `Content-Type` it expects to see, which is `text/html` in this case.

Comment: I use a GCP bucket and by default, `index.html` `Content-Type: text/html` is already set. The validator [here](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) still fail to validate: `WARN:  No metatags found`