# Twitter sharing meta tag not working for me

Tags: facebook, twitter, meta-tags

Hi Friends i am facing problem in twitter meta tag. Basically i want to populate images, title and description when we share any link over the twitter. In my website i am using following meta tag..

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimes">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="NEWARK - The guest list and parade of limousines with celebrities emerging from them seemed more suited to a red carpet event in Hollywood or New York than than a gritty stretch of Sussex Avenue near the former site of the James M. Baxter Terrace public housing project here.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg">
```

see the twitter api documentation below
[https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image](http://twitter%20API)

see my server link.
http://34.211.115.80:3000/new/alert/765

In my link Facebook working perfect but for the twitter it is not populating image. currently i put some sample code that mention in the API infect that is not working.

So can any one help me what i am doing wrong.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: might be following is the issue.
https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-failed-to-fetch-page-due-to-httpconnectiontimeout/78825

but i have not tested.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41546427/1542307

Answer (score 0):

The link you're providing is not valid. Twitter does not support dotted-IP address URLs for cards, you must have a DNS address.